# How to copy a list of directories (and their contents - subdirectories and files) into a different folder?

Tags: linux

Let's say I have 7000+ directories somewhere, each of which contains subdirectories and some files. I am only interested in a small proportion (maybe 700+) of the 7k+ directories, and I have the names of these directories. I want to copy only the 700+ directories together with their contents to a new location. How can I do that? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends entirely upon how you have formatted your your list of directories, mostly depending upon the delimiter. Assuming it is a file seperated by newlines:
`cat directories.txt | while read line; do mv $line /path/to/destination; done`

`

Comment: (1) Unless `directories.txt` is deliberately designed to be used with plain `read`, [one should strongly prefer `IFS= read -r line`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/108618). (2) In many shells [unquoted `$line` is a bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).